# Why is my Primefaces.current() returning null

Tags: jsf, primefaces

So, I have this page:

```
@Named("ManagementPage")
@ViewScoped
@Getter
@Setter
@Join(path = "/{appScope}/admin/management",
        to = "/pages/scoped/managementOverview.xhtml")
@Page(
        group = "kitchen",
        icon = "mdi mdi-comment-text",
        key = "management",
        navigation = Page.Navigation.ADMIN_SCOPED,
        outcome = "/pages/scoped/managementOverview.xhtml",
        auth = @PageAuth(value = "MANAGER_ACCESS", scoped = true))
public class ManagementPage implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private ManagementModel model;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.model.init();
    }
}
```

It's ViewScoped. And the model for it is:

```
@Log4j
@Dependent
@Getter
@Setter
public class ManagementModel implements Serializable {
...
}
```

I want, whenever I receive an event, to refresh some UI on the frontend (I'm using JSF). For that, I've created this dispatcher:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class OrderEventDispatcher {

    private static final List<ManagementModel> subscriptions = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void addSubscriber(ManagementModel subscriber) {
        subscriptions.add(subscriber);
    }

    public static void removeSubscriber(ManagementModel subscriber) {
        subscriptions.remove(subscriber);
    }

    public void observerOrderCreated(@Observes FrontendEvent frontendEvent) {
        if(frontendEvent instanceof ContentItemCreatedEvent){
            if(!"order".equals(((ContentItemCreatedEvent) frontendEvent).getTypeKey())){
                return;
            }
        }
        if(frontendEvent instanceof ContentItemChangedEvent){
            if(!"order".equals(((ContentItemChangedEvent) frontendEvent).getTypeKey())){
                return;
            }
        }
        subscriptions.forEach(ManagementModel::orderInit);
    }
}
```

(I have implemented a proper `equals` for this in my model)
For my dispatcher to work, I'm subcribing with my model to it (the methods are inside the model)

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        id = totalIds++;
        OrderEventDispatcher.addSubscriber(this);
    ...
```

And then i unsubscribe before I destroy the model:

```
@PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
        OrderEventDispatcher.removeSubscriber(this);
    }
```

And finally, the methods I call from my dispatcher:

```
public void orderInit() {
        loadMergedOrders();
        initializeDonut();
        PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("orderInit()");
}
```

I'm doing all this in order to refresh my page (even when multiple instance of the same page are open) in reaction to an event (some item is created/deleted/modified, of that the FrontendEvent takes care). Now the issue is that my PrimeFaces.current() is always returning null, I've added a breakpoint in the `init()` method and I tried using PrimeFaces.current() and it worked then, but then when I went through the Dispatcher and into the `orderInit()` with the debugger I've seen that PrimeFaces.current() now returns `null`. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? If not how to fix this then maybe a different approach to solving this. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hmmm that is really strange because PrimeFaces creates a static instance of itself `private static PrimeFaces instance = new PrimeFaces();` and that is what `current()` returns.  So I am wondering how that can be NULL unless its a weird classloader issue?

Comment: Maybe I'm using JSF/PrimeFaces in a way that's wrong? I'm sure there's a better way to do this

Comment: Most probably you've an older PrimeFaces version somewhere in the runtime classpath and that one is actually being loaded during startup instead of the expected and newer one. Cleanup your runtime classpath to get rid of duplicate different versioned libraries.